# What is the difference between a protocol and a profile in the Bluetooth stack?

Tags: bluetooth, architecture, bluetooth-lowenergy, protocols, bluetooth-gatt

I don't get how Bluetooth profiles and protocols and are distinguished.

In the Core_Specification of Bluetooth is written:

> Application interoperability in the Bluetooth system is accomplished by Bluetooth profiles. Bluetooth profiles define the required functions and features of each layer in the Bluetooth system from the PHY to L2CAP and any other protocols outside of this specification. The profile defines the vertical interactions between the layers as well as the peer-to-peer interactions of specific layers between devices. (p. 277)
> [image]

and in the book 'Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy Tools and Techniques for Low-Power Networking' by Kevin Townsend I found the following definitions:

> **Protocols**
> Building blocks used by all devices conformant to the Bluetooth specification, protocols are the layers that implement the different packet formats, routing, multiplexing, encoding, and decoding that allow data to be sent effectively between peers.
> **Profiles**
> “Vertical slices” of functionality covering either basic modes of operation required by all devices (Generic Access Profile, Generic Attribute Profile) or specific use cases (Proximity Profile, Glucose Profile), profiles essentially define how protocols should be used to achieve a particular goal, whether generic or specific.

But this did not really made it understandable for myself.

Are the Baseband & Link Manager protocols? They do not have the term 'protocol' in their name, what is weird to me. If they are not protocols, what are they?

Also I noticed that above the host part of the stack, right above the Host Controller Interface, the terms protocol can be found the most (SMP, ATT, L2CAP). Are only these really protocols? In the Controller part the term does not arise.
[image]

So the question is, what are protocols in the Bluetooth stack, what are profiles and what's the main difference?

Link to the BLE specification: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth specification defines a number of
`protocols` acting as a middle layer between profiles and lower-level Bluetooth packets. A protocol is usually employed by a limited number of profiles.
A Bluetooth `profile`, roughly speaking, corresponds to a specific use case. Profiles define the standard way of using the different protocols and their features.